# Is there a way to specify user data for Shell_NotifyIcon using NIF_INFO?

Tags: c++, shell, winapi, notifications

I would like to be able to mark each balloon with user data (an ID or void*) so when I receive a `NIN_BALLOONUSERCLICK` I can identify what balloon was clicked and perform an action meaningful to that specific notification. As far as I can tell, this isn't possible given the `NOTIFYICONDATA` structure.

Comment: There's no provision in the API for that - you'll have to roll your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I can tell, this isn't possible given the `NOTIFYICONDATA` structure

That is correct.  There is no provision in the `Shell_NotifyIcon()` API for associating user-defined data with notifications.

However, since you can only display one balloon at a time anyway, you could just store your data somewhere off to the side, and then retrieve it when the balloon is dismissed.  If you have multiple notifications, use a stack of some kind to store the data, and then have balloons pop data from the stack.

Another option would be to use a different `uCallbackMessage` value for each individual balloon when using the `NIF_MESSAGE` flag, and then have your window message handler differentiate between the message IDs as needed.  For instance, if you have an array of data, you could pick a unique base message ID (maybe from `RegisterWindowMessage()` and add the array index to it.

Comment: Your first suggestion might work except I think the OS reserves the right to not display notifications if it gets too many requests to show notifications. Perhaps you still get all the calls to the notification being dismissed/closed?

Your second solution might work. I'll have to see if that isn't a global message id stored for the whole notification icon or if it's per balloon. Also, you'd maybe run out of message ids (with RegisterWindowMessage or otherwise) unless you were able to recycle them which may lead to accidentally responding to a new notification for an old event.

Comment: From the documentation, multiple balloons are queued, they should display one after the other, and you should get `NIN_BALLOONSHOW` and `NIN_BALLOON(HIDE|TIMEOUT|USERCLICK)` for each one. Except in the case where "quite time" is active, then you don't get anything unless you specify the `NIIF_RESPECT_QUIET_TIME` flag then you will get `NIN_BALLOONHIDE` if you try to display a balloon during "quiet time".

Comment: `Shell_NotifyIcon()` lets you specify a different `uCallbackMessage` ID per notification. I wasn't suggesting you call `RegisterWindowMessage()` for each notification, I was suggesting you call it **once** to get a base ID and then you can add an offset to it on each notification.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Unfortunately the first option doesn't work. I tried to display 100 balloon tips in a row and only the last 20 were displayed and sent the uCallbackMessage when clicked, closed, or timed out. The second option isn't an option for me unfortunately because I'm using a wrapper around Shell_NotifyIcon that I have no control over.

Comment: If you have control over specifying the value of the `uCallbackMessage`, and can actually handle the message when it is sent, then the second option will work for you.